# Change light intensity back and forth over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, light

How can I change the light intensity value from 3.08 back to 1.0 after 2 seconds. I  have comment in my code for additional info

```
public class Point_LightG : MonoBehaviour {

    public Light point_light;
    float timer;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        point_light = GetComponent<Light>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
        lights();
    }

    public void lights()
    {
        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            point_light.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(1.0f, 3.08f, Time.time);
            timer = 2f;
        }

        // so after my light intensity reach 3.08 I need it to gradually change back to 1.0 after 2 seconds.
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically, you want to change it from 3.08 to 1.0  within 2 seconds then back to 3.08. Back and forth?

Comment: yes sir back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lerp between two values, just use the `Mathf.PingPong` with the `Mathf.Lerp` and provide a speed the lerp should happen at.

```
public Light point_light;
public float speed = 0.36f;

float intensity1 = 3.08f;
float intensity2 = 1.0f;


void Start()
{
    point_light = GetComponent<Light>();
}

void Update()
{
    //PingPong between 0 and 1
    float time = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1);
    point_light.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(intensity1, intensity2, time);
}
```

---

If you prefer to use a **duration** instead of a **speed** variable to control the light intensity then you that is better done with a coroutine function and just the `Mathf.Lerp` function with a simple timer. The lerp can then be done within x seconds.

```
IEnumerator LerpLightRepeat()
{
    while (true)
    {
        //Lerp to intensity1
        yield return LerpLight(point_light, intensity1, 2f);
        //Lerp to intensity2
        yield return LerpLight(point_light, intensity2, 2f);
    }
}

IEnumerator LerpLight(Light targetLight, float toIntensity, float duration)
{
    float currentIntensity = targetLight.intensity;

    float counter = 0;
    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        targetLight.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(currentIntensity, toIntensity, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public Light point_light;

float intensity1 = 3.08f;
float intensity2 = 1.0f;

void Start()
{
    point_light = GetComponent<Light>();
    StartCoroutine(LerpLightRepeat());
}
```

Comment: Oh nice, I didnt even know about the pingpong function of mathf I need to dive into the documentation again

Comment: @Eddge Yeah. Dig the doc for some Unity APIonce in a while and you'll be surprised to see functions you didn't know existed.  `Vector3.Lerp` is mostly used but some people don't know that `Mathf.Lerp` and `Quaternion.Lerp` exist too.

Comment: Thanks  sir, works like a charm. I'll be experimenting values using your codes :D

Comment: I know you're trying to be respectful but you don't have to call people sir. They could be the-same age as you. You are welcome!